# Android 4.0.3 - Playing consecutive videos with VideoView from SD Card successfully, but the GUI "enlarge-shrink" while video switching

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I have a videoView and a "next" button in my Linearlayout, when I press "next", no matter the video is playing or not, the next video will be played, and it works.
But every time I press "next", the whole scene will enlarge first then shrink back to the original size.
My Android version is 4.0.3, and I use Eclipse as developing tool.
There shows no error but information in LogCat as below, I have no idea how to solve it.

---

#### LogCat

> 01-02 00:14:05.849: I/VideoView(1677): Layout changed,left=149 top=0 right=1130 bottom=654
>   01-02 00:14:05.849: I/VideoView(1677): Layout changed,oldLeft=149 oldTop=0 oldRight=1130 oldBottom=654
>   01-02 00:14:05.849: I/VideoView(1677): .left=149.top=0.right=1130.bottom=654.oldLeft=149.oldTop=0.oldRight=1130.oldBottom=654.Rotation=0
>   01-02 00:14:06.209: I/VideoView(1677): Layout changed,left=204 top=0 right=1076 bottom=654
>   01-02 00:14:06.209: I/VideoView(1677): Layout changed,oldLeft=149 oldTop=0 oldRight=1130 oldBottom=654
>   01-02 00:14:06.209: I/VideoView(1677): .left=204.top=0.right=1076.bottom=654.oldLeft=149.oldTop=0.oldRight=1130.oldBottom=654.Rotation=0

---

Hope there is anyone can help, thanks!!

---

#### My layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".VideoViewActivity" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
        />        
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" />
```

#### My activity

```
package com.example.testvideoview;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private List<String> videoList = null;
    private static String mediaPath = null;
    private String subDir = "/external_sdcard/";
    private int playIndex = 0;
    private Button nextButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        mediaPath = sdcard + subDir;

        videoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        videoList.add("aaa.mpg");
        videoList.add("bbb.mpg");
        videoList.add("ccc.mpg");
        videoList.add("ddd.mp4");

        videoView.setVideoPath(mediaPath+videoList.get(playIndex));
        videoView.requestFocus();    
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                videoView.stopPlayback();
                playNextFile();
            }
        });     

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void playNextFile(){
        if(videoView.isPlaying())
            videoView.stopPlayback();
        playIndex++;
        if(playIndex == videoList.size())
            playIndex = 0;
        videoView.setVideoPath(mediaPath+videoList.get(playIndex));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                         
                videoView.start();
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a test, does the same obvious redrawing occur is you use fixed heights rather than calculated weights in your LinearLayout? If so, you could switch to a parent layout like ReleativeLayout where you would not need to use the weights.

Comment: Jason, I've tested it but the redrawing is the same.
Still thank you for the suggestion, I don't feel alone anymore.
Happy Holiday!
:)